# Can the correlation with column mean be a reasonable row-wise similarity metric?

Tags: r, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, correlation, similarities

### Backgrounds

Suppose we have a data matrix as follows, where each row is an independent observation.

$$
\mathbf{X} := \begin{bmatrix}
x_{11} & x_{12} & \cdots & x_{1m} \\
x_{21} & x_{22} & \cdots & x_{2m} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
x_{n1} & x_{n2} & \cdots & x_{nm} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

For simplicity, let us assume $\displaystyle \mathbf{x} := \left[\mathbf{x}_1, \mathbf{x}_2, \cdots, \mathbf{x}_m\right] \sim \mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{\mu}, \mathcal{\Sigma}_\mathbf{x} \right)$, and each row $x_{i\cdot}$ is a random sample of $\mathbf{x}$.

Now we can define the column mean $\overline{x} := \left[ \overline{x_{\cdot 1}}, \overline{x_{\cdot 2}}, \cdots, \overline{x_{\cdot m}} \right]$, where bars: sample mean and $x_{\cdot j} := \left[x_{1j}, x_{2j}, \cdots, x_{nj}\right]^T$.

Then, we can define the following metric whose meaning is the **distance toward the center**:

$$
\vec{r} := \left[r_1,r_2,\cdots,r_n\right], \ \  r_i := \mathbf{r} \left( x_{i\cdot}, \overline{x} \right)
$$

where $\mathbf{r}(k,l)$ denotes the sample Pearson correlation coefficient for input vectors $k,l$.

---

### Question

I would like to **study the behavior** of this metric $\vec{r}=\vec{r}\left(\mathbf{X}\right)$ for a given data matrix $\mathbf{X}$.

> **Is there any similar metric related to this measure?**

Please feel free to educate me with your comments or relevant papers.

---

### Try

I viewed $\vec{r}_i$ as an estimator for $\vec{\rho}_i := \mathbf{r}\left( x_{i\cdot}, \mu \right)$. Then it would be useful to study the distribution of $\vec{\rho}_i$. First of all, let $\mathbf{c}\left(\cdot,\cdot \right)$: sample covariance function. Then

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{c}\left( x_{i\cdot}, \mu \right) &= \frac{1}{m-1} \sum_{j=1}^m \left(x_{ij}-\overline{x_{i\cdot}} \right) \left(\mu_j-\overline{\mu} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{m-1} \left( \mu^T x_{i\cdot} - \overline{\mu} \mathbb{1}^T x_{i\cdot} \right) \\
&= \frac{\mu^T \left[I - m\mathbb{1}\mathbb{1}^T \right] x_{i\cdot} }{m-1}  \\
&\sim \mathcal{N} \left( \frac{\mu^T \left[I - m\mathbb{1}\mathbb{1}^T \right] \mu }{m-1},  \frac{\mu^T \left[I - m\mathbb{1}\mathbb{1}^T \right] \mathcal{\Sigma} \left[I - m\mathbb{1}\mathbb{1}^T \right] \mu }{(m-1)^2} \right)
\end{aligned}
$$

But from here I cannot proceed to find any interesting properties.

---

To investigate the relationship of $\vec{r}\left(\mathbf{X}\right)$ with other distance metrics, I made the following `R` codes.

```
library(MASS)
N = 1000
x = c(7,3,9,1)
S = matrix(c(6,1,1,1,
             1,2,1,3,
             1,1,5,2,
             1,3,2,8),4,4)
X = mvrnorm(n=N, x, S)

r = apply(X, 1, function(y) cor(x,y)) # r as defined above
r_cov = apply(X, 1, function(y) cov(x,y)) # use covariance rather than correlation

mahal   = mahalanobis(X, x, S) # Mahalanobis distance with true mean and covar.
L1dist  = apply(X, 1, function(y) mean(abs(x-y))) # L1 dist := E[|true-pred|]
L2dist  = apply(X, 1, function(y) mean((x-y)^2))  # L2 dist := E[|true-pred|^2]

par(mfrow=c(3,2))
plot(r, mahal); plot(r_cov, mahal)
plot(r, L1dist); plot(r_cov, L1dist)
plot(r, L2dist); plot(r_cov, L2dist)
```

The above code generates the following plot, which depicts the relationship of $\vec{r}$ with **Mahalanobis distance**, **L1 distance from mean vector**, and **L2 distance from mean vector**. As you can see, the relationship is quite **nonlinear**.
[image]

Comment: You have $N$ observations of a multivatiate random variable $x$ of $M$ dimensions. You calculate the means over observations, and then correlate that vector with each observation individually, obtaining samples from a new scalar random variable. Do I understand the problem correctly? May I ask why are you interested in this metric - do you have some intuition why it should be informative? In a purely mathematical sense, the operation you propose is a bit dodgy - you take correlation over dimensions, not over samples. so the interpretation may strongly depend on dimension $M$.

Comment: If you want a similarity measure for checking if all dimensions behave similarly, why not use the (fraction of) variance explained by the 1st eigenvalue?

Comment: @AleksejsFomins Yes, I think you understand the problem correctly. Except that the expression "obtaining samples from a new scalar random variable" sounds quite elusive for me.

Comment: @AleksejsFomins As I connoted by the figures in the last paragraph, my intuition was as follows: it is calculated quite similarly(please bear with me, in a broad sense) to the measure like Mahalanobis distance: it can measure the similarity from the "centroid" defined by the sample space.

Comment: @AleksejsFomins Well I intend to measure the row-wise similarity to the centroid, rather than the level of similarity across dimensions.

Comment: About scalar random variable - you apply a transformation, which takes $N$ multivariate random variables as inputs and produces $N$ univariate random variables as output. But that is just a way of looking at it, not very relevant for the question

Comment: So, basically, the interpretation is as follows: say you have a 100-dimensional random variable, which denotes a some 1D landscape profile. The question is if the shape of some given example landscape is similar to the average landscape, like, has peaks and valleys at the same spots. Makes sense. But I still miss the ultimate purpose. Let's say you computed this metric for every example, what do you do with it afterwards? Are you simply interested to check which examples are most representative of the mean, or is there is a deeper goal?

Comment: @AleksejsFomins Okay actually there are additional columns to $\mathbf{X}$, but it is assumed that those columns are totally excluded from the procedures described in the text above. I would like to check the relationship between those row-wise similarity measures and those columns.

Comment: ok, so now it seems like you have two goals - to analytically understand this novel metric, and to perform a certain type of analysis. So why don't you just perform your analysis using the more common metrics you outlined above (L1, L2, Mahalonobis)? Are you seeking a novel metric because the above are unsatisfactory in some way?

Comment: @AleksejsFomins Actually the story is the opposite. Originally I intended to debunk the correlation metric in favor of the more common metrics. Now I'm just interested in the characteristics of the novel metric itself..